# Post iso8583 in java

Tags: java, iso8583

How to collect and send a message in iso 8583 format, in java? Something like this:

```
30 38 30 30 82 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 11 13 12 53 20 12 34 56 03 01
```

I tried to build using the library https://github.com/imohsenb/ISO8583-Message-Client-java. Collects incorrectly.

```
30 38 30 30 82 20 08 00 22 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 11 13 12 53 20 12 34 56 03 01
```

Code:

```
public class ClientSocket {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ISOException, ISOClientException, IOException {
        ISOMessage isoMessage = ISOMessageBuilder.Packer(VERSION.V1987)
                .networkManagement()
                .mti(MESSAGE_FUNCTION.Request, MESSAGE_ORIGIN.Acquirer)
                .processCode("0000000")
                .setField(FIELDS.F7_TransmissionDataTime,  "1113125320")
                .setField(FIELDS.F11_STAN,  "1234560301")
                .setHeader("303830308220")
                .build();

        ISOClient client = ISOClientBuilder.createSocket("172.20.104.69", 5803)
                .build();
        System.out.println("isoMessage " + isoMessage);

        client.connect();
        String response = Arrays.toString(client.sendMessageSync(isoMessage));
        System.out.println("response = " + response);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the message you got from the code:

30 38 30 30 82 20 - message header you have set (it contains the string 0800 that looks like MTI - is this what you had in mind?)

08 00 - actual MTI for network management

22 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 - bitmap indicating that field 3,7,11 are present

00 00 00 - processing code (field 3)

00 - additional 00 byte stuffed after processing code (probably due to the fact you set processing code to odd number of characters and the library and it was not truncated as it should be)

11 13 12 53 20 - date/time (field 7)

12 34 56 - STAN (field 11)

03 01 - characters you set as STAN, but they will not be treated as such, because stan is 6 digits according to ISO specs

It's quite hard to understand what you were trying to achieve looking at the target message.

I would assume that what you are trying to achieve is actually a different message - it starts with MTI in ASCII, contains second bitmap, indicates that fields 7,11 and 70 are present.

Field 7 would then be: 11 13 12 53 20

Field 11 would be: 12 34 56

Field 70 would be: 03 01

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I sort of figured it out. Now I need to parse hex iso 8583 into a readable form. I want something like this:
Message size 68
Header A4M08000
Message type 0810
P0007 Transmission date and time LEN = 10 OFFS = 44 '1121125327'
P0011 Systems Trace Audit Number LEN = 6 OFFS = 54 '153277'
P0039 Response code LEN = 5 OFFS = 60 '00000'
P0070 Network Management Code LEN = 3 OFFS = 65 '301' Can you tell me about how to do this?